# Package only works properly in IDLE or Interpreter, but not independantly?

Tags: python, audio, python-idle

I have been trying to add audio cues to a program I am working on using Py-Audiere. However, the sounds only play when I use the run command within IDlE (or manually put it into the interpreter), and then only if the calls are done in certain ways. This is the code snippet:

```
import audiere

filename = 'Bell'
d = audiere.open_device()
filename += '.mp3'
bell = d.open_file(filename)
bell.repeating = True

def play_tone():
    bell.play()

play_tone()
```

If I run it outside of IDLE, nothing happens. If I run it in IDLE, but move all of it into the function and pass the filename, nothing happens.

I am very confused as to what is going on with this library, and at this point I am not sure I should even be using this one. Does anyone know what is going on or have an alternative (I considered GStreamer, but I can't figure out their documentation)?

Comment: What does PyAudiere do if it can't find the file you specify?

Answer (score 1):

I've experimented a bit with audiere (never heard of this library before) and it looks like it plays the sound in a new thread in the background.

In your code snippet you tell audiere to start playing your bell, but you never give it enough time to completely play it. When you run this in Idle or the Python interpreter this doesn't matter as the Python process is still running and so the sound just plays in the background.

Their [website](http://pyaudiere.org/) has a small snippet that shows how you can accomplish this:

```
import time
def play_tone():
    bell.play()
    while bell.playing:
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

As for gstreamer, the documentation can be a bit complex if you never used it before. The best way I found out to learn how to use it is just to experiment with it. Some good points to start is this [tutorial](http://pygstdocs.berlios.de/pygst-tutorial/index.html) that explains the basics of how gstreamer works. This [code snippet](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~jonobacon/python-snippets/trunk/view/head:/gstreamer/playall.py) shows how to play a single sound file with it. And this [irc conversation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MeetingLogs/OpWeek1003/Gstreamer) is helpful too, if you feel like reading over it.